symfony 6 login not working on production
I have two login forms.
One for users:
https://www.********/login
This login works on development but doesn't work on production. On production it simply redirects to the login page with no error messages displayed.
I also have a login page for admin users:
https://www.********/admin/login
This one works on both development and production.
My security.yaml:
security:
enable_authenticator_manager: true
providers:
    users:
        mongodb:
            class: 'App\Document\User\User'
            property: 'username'
            
password_hashers:
    App\Document\User\User:
        algorithm: auto
        
erase_credentials: false

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
        
    admin:
        pattern:    ^/admin         
        logout:
            path: public_logout_admin        
        form_login:
            login_path: public_login_admin
            check_path: public_login_admin
            default_target_path: admin_prepaid_order_list
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
        user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker
        
    main:
        pattern:    ^/    
        logout:
            path: public_logout                         
        form_login:
            login_path: public_login
            check_path: public_login
            default_target_path: business_browse_top_categories                
        switch_user: { role: ROLE_ADMIN }
        access_denied_handler: App\Security\AccessDeniedHandler
        user_checker: App\Security\UserChecker 

access_control:
    - { path: '^/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/signup', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/password-reset', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/business', roles: ROLE_BUSINESS }
    
    - { path: '/admin/login', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '/admin/logout', roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }
    - { path: '^/admin', roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
    
role_hierarchy:        
    ROLE_BUSINESS_TERMS_ACCEPTED: ROLE_BUSINESS        
    ROLE_BUSINESS_ACCEPTED: ROLE_BUSINESS_TERMS_ACCEPTED        
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_BUSINESS_ACCEPTED, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]    

What is wrong?
Andras
Tried these: switching between development and production, removing and adding parts of dev and prod config, checking Symfony code (onAuthenticationSuccess returns the right RedirectResponse object but afterwards it still redirects to login).

If I set auto_generate_proxy_classes to true in doctrine_mongodb.yaml, login works on production too:
doctrine_mongodb:
...
when@prod:
doctrine_mongodb:
auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
